# How to make initial view controller present again in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have an app that uses a main screen (below) and then a barcode scanner framework to scan in a barcode and then I will code an action to perform. However, the problem I am having is that in the code it takes me back to the scanning screen. I have tried to use `present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)` and it does not know what VC1 is.

I assigned VC1 in Xcode under storyboard id (see below):

[image: Storyboard ID for VC1]

Below is my code here for view controller.swift. Now the code takes you back to the scanning screen, but I want to go back to VC1 the main view controller.

```
import UIKit
import BarcodeScanner

var presentedViewController: UIViewController?

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var pushScannerButton: UIButton!

    //Present view and handle barcode scanning
    @IBAction func handleScannerPush(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let viewController = makeBarcodeScannerViewController()
        viewController.title = "Barcode Scanner"
        present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func makeBarcodeScannerViewController() -> BarcodeScannerViewController {
        let viewController = BarcodeScannerViewController()
        viewController.codeDelegate = self
        viewController.errorDelegate = self
        viewController.dismissalDelegate = self
        return viewController
    }
}

// MARK: - BarcodeScannerCodeDelegate

extension ViewController: BarcodeScannerCodeDelegate {
    func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didCaptureCode code: String, type: String) {
        print("Barcode Data: \(code)")
        print("Symbology Type: \(type)")

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

//       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
//           controller.resetWithError()
//        }
    }
}

// MARK: - BarcodeScannerErrorDelegate

extension ViewController: BarcodeScannerErrorDelegate {
    func scanner(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController, didReceiveError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}

// MARK: - BarcodeScannerDismissalDelegate

extension ViewController: BarcodeScannerDismissalDelegate {
    func scannerDidDismiss(_ controller: BarcodeScannerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: just do [ dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) ] not controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil).

Comment: @vivekDas I have included the hierarchy [link](https://ibb.co/cTBLpT )here. If you dismiss the view controller it will go back to barcode scanner view controller, and not the entry view controller.

Comment: what is vc1 ? is it ViewController ?

Comment: @vivekDas Yes VC1 is a view controller. If you look at the graphic in the previous comment it's the first VC in the graphic. The attributes for it are included in the attached graphic above where I show VC1.